# PhoneGap 2.7 not intercepting Ajax requests

Tags: ios, ajax, cordova, sencha-touch, phonegap-build

I tried to make an ajax request from sencha-touch but the request is not getting intercepted by cordova 2.7.  I am setting the userAgent as the vc header. We were using Cordova 2.2 earlier with the same setup and the Ajax requests were intercepted well and good. Am I missing something here?

Comment: did you ever figure this out Imran?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$.ajax({
     type: //get/post/put/delete,
     url: //Your url,
     data://Example: JSON.stringify(credentials),
     async: false,
     beforeSend: function(x) {
      if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
       x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
      }
      x.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
    },
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data){
                                     },
     error: function(xhr, status, errorThrown){
                                     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whitelisting. In config.xml add
`<access origin=".*"/>`    and try